Numba parallelization doesn't help performance in Monte-Carlo simulation?
This is a follow-up question to a question I asked before, but I think I should start over. I am trying to implement a Monte-Carlo simulation of pi, and I am using numba to improve performance. Since each iteration of the loop is independent of the others, I thought I could get better performance with parallel=True and numba.prange. I tried it and got that for small values of n, the parallelization isn't worth it. I tried an improved version where I use parallelization after a certain threshold for n is crossed, but I found it performs worse than my previous attempts most of the time. I now have a compression of 3 versions of the algorithm: a regular one without parallelization, a parallel version using numba.prange and an "improved" hybrid version that uses parallelization after a specified threshold for n is crossed:
from datetime import timedelta
from time import perf_counter

import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt

jit_opts = dict(
    nopython=True, nogil=True, cache=False, error_model="numpy", fastmath=True
)

rng = np.random.default_rng()


@nb.jit(
    [
        nb.types.Tuple((nb.bool_[:], nb.int64))(nb.float64[:, :]),
        nb.types.Tuple((nb.bool_[:], nb.int32))(nb.float32[:, :]),
    ],
    **jit_opts,
    parallel=True,
)
def count_points_in_circle_parallel(
    points: npt.NDArray[float],
) -> tuple[npt.NDArray[bool], int]:
    in_circle = np.empty(points.shape[0], dtype=np.bool_)
    in_circle_count = 0
    for i in nb.prange(points.shape[0]):
        in_ = in_circle[i] = points[i, 0] ** 2 + points[i, 1] ** 2 < 1
        in_circle_count += in_
    return in_circle, in_circle_count


def monte_carlo_pi_parallel(
    n: int,
) -> tuple[npt.NDArray[float], npt.NDArray[bool], float]:
    points = rng.random((n, 2))
    in_circle, count = count_points_in_circle_parallel(points)
    return points, in_circle, 4 * count / n


@nb.jit(
    [
        nb.types.Tuple((nb.bool_[:], nb.int64))(nb.float64[:, :]),
        nb.types.Tuple((nb.bool_[:], nb.int32))(nb.float32[:, :]),
    ],
    **jit_opts,
    parallel=False,
)
def count_points_in_circle(points: npt.NDArray[float]) -> tuple[npt.NDArray[bool], int]:
    in_circle = np.empty(points.shape[0], dtype=np.bool_)
    in_circle_count = 0
    for i in range(points.shape[0]):
        in_ = in_circle[i] = points[i, 0] ** 2 + points[i, 1] ** 2 < 1
        in_circle_count += in_
    return in_circle, in_circle_count


def monte_carlo_pi(n: int) -> tuple[npt.NDArray[float], npt.NDArray[bool], float]:
    points = rng.random((n, 2))
    in_circle, count = count_points_in_circle(points)
    return points, in_circle, 4 * count / n


def count_points_in_circle_improved(
    points: npt.NDArray[float],
) -> tuple[npt.NDArray[bool], int]:
    in_circle = np.empty(points.shape[0], dtype=np.bool_)
    in_circle_count = 0
    for i in nb.prange(points.shape[0]):
        in_ = in_circle[i] = points[i, 0] ** 2 + points[i, 1] ** 2 < 1
        in_circle_count += in_
    return in_circle, in_circle_count


count_points_in_circle_improved_parallel = nb.jit(
    [
        nb.types.Tuple((nb.bool_[:], nb.int64))(nb.float64[:, :]),
        nb.types.Tuple((nb.bool_[:], nb.int32))(nb.float32[:, :]),
    ],
    **jit_opts,
    parallel=True,
)(count_points_in_circle_improved)
count_points_in_circle_improved = nb.jit(
    [
        nb.types.Tuple((nb.bool_[:], nb.int64))(nb.float64[:, :]),
        nb.types.Tuple((nb.bool_[:], nb.int32))(nb.float32[:, :]),
    ],
    **jit_opts,
    parallel=False,
)(count_points_in_circle_improved)


def monte_carlo_pi_improved(
    n: int, parallel_threshold: int = 1000
) -> tuple[npt.NDArray[float], npt.NDArray[bool], float]:
    points = rng.random((n, 2))
    in_circle, count = (
        count_points_in_circle_improved_parallel(points)
        if n > parallel_threshold
        else count_points_in_circle_improved(points)
    )
    return points, in_circle, 4 * count / n


def main() -> None:
    n_values = 10 ** np.arange(1, 9)
    n_values = np.concatenate(
        ([10], n_values)
    )  # Duplicate 10 to avoid startup overhead
    time_results = np.empty((len(n_values), 3), dtype=np.float64)

    if jit_opts.get("cache", False):
        print("Using cached JIT compilation")
    else:
        print("Using JIT compilation without caching")
    print()

    print("Using parallel count_points_in_circle")
    for i, n in enumerate(n_values):
        start = perf_counter()
        points, in_circle, pi_approx = monte_carlo_pi_parallel(n)
        end = perf_counter()
        duration = end - start
        time_results[i, 0] = duration
        delta = timedelta(seconds=duration)
        elapsed_msg = (
            f"[{delta} (Raw time: {duration} s)]"
            if delta
            else f"[Raw time: {duration} s]"
        )
        print(
            f"n = {n:,}:".ljust(20),
            f"\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER PI} \N{ALMOST EQUAL TO} {pi_approx}".ljust(20),
            elapsed_msg,
        )

    print()
    print("Using non-parallel count_points_in_circle")
    for i, n in enumerate(n_values):
        start = perf_counter()
        points, in_circle, pi_approx = monte_carlo_pi(n)
        end = perf_counter()
        duration = end - start
        delta = timedelta(seconds=duration)
        time_results[i, 1] = duration
        elapsed_msg = (
            f"[{delta} (Raw time: {duration} s)]"
            if delta
            else f"[Raw time: {duration} s]"
        )
        print(
            f"n = {n:,}:".ljust(20),
            f"\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER PI} \N{ALMOST EQUAL TO} {pi_approx}".ljust(20),
            elapsed_msg,
        )

    print()
    print("Improved version:")
    for i, n in enumerate(n_values):
        start = perf_counter()
        points, in_circle, pi_approx = monte_carlo_pi_improved(n)
        end = perf_counter()
        duration = end - start
        delta = timedelta(seconds=duration)
        time_results[i, 2] = duration
        elapsed_msg = (
            f"[{delta} (Raw time: {duration} s)]"
            if delta
            else f"[Raw time: {duration} s]"
        )
        print(
            f"n = {n:,}:".ljust(20),
            f"\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER PI} \N{ALMOST EQUAL TO} {pi_approx}".ljust(20),
            elapsed_msg,
        )

    print()
    print("Comparison:")
    result_types = ("parallel", "non-parallel", "improved")
    for n, res in zip(n_values, time_results):
        res_idx = np.argsort(res)
        print(
            f"n = {n:,}:".ljust(20),
            f"{result_types[res_idx[0]]} \N{LESS-THAN OR EQUAL TO} "
            f"{result_types[res_idx[1]]} \N{LESS-THAN OR EQUAL TO} "
            f"{result_types[res_idx[2]]}",
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

(I know, I know, this code isn't very clean and has repetitions, but it's for testing purposes, and I'll end up with one of the algorithms in the end). I tried running it with cache=True and cache=False to check if it helps with something and the results are very confusing. It looks like sometimes the non-parallel version is faster even for large values of n and the hybrid version doesn't really improve anything. Here's an example of the results I get:

These results are very confusing and they're not consistent. In a different run, I got that the non-parallel version is faster, and in another run, I got that the parallel version is faster. It looks like I am doing something wrong here, but I can't understand what's going on. Why do I not see a consistent performance improvement in the parallel version, especially for large values of n, and why my hybrid approach doesn't seem to improve performance in most cases? Any insight into what's happening here would be appreciated.
Edit:
Following @Jerome Richard's answer, I modified the code to pre-allocate buffers and reuse them for all of my tests. The results are still weird to me: the parallel version performs the worst most of the time, even for large n. I even included n = 500,000,000 to push the limits further (apparently, my computer can't handle 1,000,000,000 so had to cut it in half), but the parallel version still underperforms. Why do I not see any significant improvement for the parallel or hybrid version of the algorithm?
The modified code:
from datetime import timedelta
from time import perf_counter

import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt

jit_opts = dict(
    nopython=True, nogil=True, cache=False, error_model="numpy", fastmath=True
)

rng = np.random.default_rng()


@nb.jit(
    [
        nb.types.Tuple((nb.bool_[:], nb.int64))(nb.float64[:, :], nb.bool_[:]),
        nb.types.Tuple((nb.bool_[:], nb.int32))(nb.float32[:, :], nb.bool_[:]),
    ],
    **jit_opts,
    parallel=True,
)
def count_points_in_circle_parallel(
    points: npt.NDArray[float], in_circle: npt.NDArray[bool]
) -> tuple[npt.NDArray[bool], int]:
    in_circle_count = 0
    for i in nb.prange(points.shape[0]):
        in_ = in_circle[i] = points[i, 0] ** 2 + points[i, 1] ** 2 < 1
        in_circle_count += in_
    return in_circle, in_circle_count


def monte_carlo_pi_parallel(
    n: int,
    out: npt.NDArray[float] | None = None,
    in_circle_out: npt.NDArray[bool] | None = None,
) -> tuple[npt.NDArray[float], npt.NDArray[bool], float]:
    points = rng.random((n, 2), out=out)
    if in_circle_out is None:
        in_circle_out = np.empty(n, dtype=np.bool_)
    in_circle, count = count_points_in_circle_parallel(points, in_circle_out)
    return points, in_circle, 4 * count / n


@nb.jit(
    [
        nb.types.Tuple((nb.bool_[:], nb.int64))(nb.float64[:, :], nb.bool_[:]),
        nb.types.Tuple((nb.bool_[:], nb.int32))(nb.float32[:, :], nb.bool_[:]),
    ],
    **jit_opts,
    parallel=False,
)
def count_points_in_circle(
    points: npt.NDArray[float], in_circle: npt.NDArray[bool]
) -> tuple[npt.NDArray[bool], int]:
    in_circle_count = 0
    for i in range(points.shape[0]):
        in_ = in_circle[i] = points[i, 0] ** 2 + points[i, 1] ** 2 < 1
        in_circle_count += in_
    return in_circle, in_circle_count


def monte_carlo_pi(
    n: int,
    out: npt.NDArray[float] | None = None,
    in_circle_out: npt.NDArray[bool] | None = None,
) -> tuple[npt.NDArray[float], npt.NDArray[bool], float]:
    points = rng.random((n, 2), out=out)
    if in_circle_out is None:
        in_circle_out = np.empty(n, dtype=np.bool_)
    in_circle, count = count_points_in_circle(points, in_circle_out)
    return points, in_circle, 4 * count / n


def count_points_in_circle_improved(
    points: npt.NDArray[float], in_circle: npt.NDArray[bool]
) -> tuple[npt.NDArray[bool], int]:
    in_circle_count = 0
    for i in nb.prange(points.shape[0]):
        in_ = in_circle[i] = points[i, 0] ** 2 + points[i, 1] ** 2 < 1
        in_circle_count += in_
    return in_circle, in_circle_count


count_points_in_circle_improved_parallel = nb.jit(
    [
        nb.types.Tuple((nb.bool_[:], nb.int64))(nb.float64[:, :], nb.bool_[:]),
        nb.types.Tuple((nb.bool_[:], nb.int32))(nb.float32[:, :], nb.bool_[:]),
    ],
    **jit_opts,
    parallel=True,
)(count_points_in_circle_improved)
count_points_in_circle_improved = nb.jit(
    [
        nb.types.Tuple((nb.bool_[:], nb.int64))(nb.float64[:, :], nb.bool_[:]),
        nb.types.Tuple((nb.bool_[:], nb.int32))(nb.float32[:, :], nb.bool_[:]),
    ],
    **jit_opts,
    parallel=False,
)(count_points_in_circle_improved)


def monte_carlo_pi_improved(
    n: int,
    parallel_threshold: int = 1000,
    out: npt.NDArray[float] | None = None,
    in_circle_out: npt.NDArray[bool] | None = None,
) -> tuple[npt.NDArray[float], npt.NDArray[bool], float]:
    points = rng.random((n, 2), out=out)
    if in_circle_out is None:
        in_circle_out = np.empty(n, dtype=np.bool_)
    in_circle, count = (
        count_points_in_circle_improved_parallel(points, in_circle_out)
        if n > parallel_threshold
        else count_points_in_circle_improved(points, in_circle_out)
    )
    return points, in_circle, 4 * count / n


def main() -> None:
    n_values = 10 ** np.arange(1, 9)
    n_values = np.concatenate(
        ([10], n_values, [500_000_000])
    )  # Duplicate 10 to avoid startup overhead
    n_max = n_values.max()
    buffer = np.empty((n_max, 2), dtype=np.float64)
    in_circle_buffer = np.empty(n_max, dtype=np.bool_)
    use_preallocated_buffer = False
    time_results = np.empty((len(n_values), 3), dtype=np.float64)

    if jit_opts.get("cache", False):
        print("Using cached JIT compilation")
    else:
        print("Using JIT compilation without caching")
    if use_preallocated_buffer:
        print("Using preallocated buffers")
    else:
        print("Not using preallocated buffers")
    print()

    print("Using parallel count_points_in_circle")
    for i, n in enumerate(n_values):
        start = perf_counter()
        if use_preallocated_buffer:
            points, in_circle, pi_approx = monte_carlo_pi_parallel(
                n, out=buffer[:n], in_circle_out=in_circle_buffer[:n]
            )
        else:
            points, in_circle, pi_approx = monte_carlo_pi_parallel(n)
        end = perf_counter()
        duration = end - start
        time_results[i, 0] = duration
        delta = timedelta(seconds=duration)
        elapsed_msg = (
            f"[{delta} (Raw time: {duration} s)]"
            if delta
            else f"[Raw time: {duration} s]"
        )
        print(
            f"n = {n:,}:".ljust(20),
            f"\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER PI} \N{ALMOST EQUAL TO} {pi_approx}".ljust(20),
            elapsed_msg,
        )

    print()
    print("Using non-parallel count_points_in_circle")
    for i, n in enumerate(n_values):
        start = perf_counter()
        if use_preallocated_buffer:
            points, in_circle, pi_approx = monte_carlo_pi(
                n, out=buffer[:n], in_circle_out=in_circle_buffer[:n]
            )
        else:
            points, in_circle, pi_approx = monte_carlo_pi(n)
        end = perf_counter()
        duration = end - start
        delta = timedelta(seconds=duration)
        time_results[i, 1] = duration
        elapsed_msg = (
            f"[{delta} (Raw time: {duration} s)]"
            if delta
            else f"[Raw time: {duration} s]"
        )
        print(
            f"n = {n:,}:".ljust(20),
            f"\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER PI} \N{ALMOST EQUAL TO} {pi_approx}".ljust(20),
            elapsed_msg,
        )

    print()
    print("Improved version:")
    for i, n in enumerate(n_values):
        start = perf_counter()
        if use_preallocated_buffer:
            points, in_circle, pi_approx = monte_carlo_pi_improved(
                n, out=buffer[:n], in_circle_out=in_circle_buffer[:n]
            )
        else:
            points, in_circle, pi_approx = monte_carlo_pi_improved(n)
        end = perf_counter()
        duration = end - start
        delta = timedelta(seconds=duration)
        time_results[i, 2] = duration
        elapsed_msg = (
            f"[{delta} (Raw time: {duration} s)]"
            if delta
            else f"[Raw time: {duration} s]"
        )
        print(
            f"n = {n:,}:".ljust(20),
            f"\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER PI} \N{ALMOST EQUAL TO} {pi_approx}".ljust(20),
            elapsed_msg,
        )

    print()
    print("Comparison:")
    result_types = ("parallel", "non-parallel", "improved")
    for n, res in zip(n_values, time_results):
        res_idx = np.argsort(res)
        print(
            f"n = {n:,}:".ljust(20),
            f"{result_types[res_idx[0]]} \N{LESS-THAN OR EQUAL TO} "
            f"{result_types[res_idx[1]]} \N{LESS-THAN OR EQUAL TO} "
            f"{result_types[res_idx[2]]}",
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

The results with pre-allocation:
Using JIT compilation without caching
Using preallocated buffers

Using parallel count_points_in_circle
n = 10:              π ≈ 2.8              [0:00:00.018026 (Raw time: 0.018026399999996556 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 2.4              [0:00:00.000072 (Raw time: 7.180000000062137e-05 s)]
n = 100:             π ≈ 3.12             [0:00:00.000047 (Raw time: 4.7400000028119393e-05 s)]
n = 1,000:           π ≈ 3.208            [0:00:00.000075 (Raw time: 7.499999998117346e-05 s)]
n = 10,000:          π ≈ 3.1392           [0:00:00.000235 (Raw time: 0.00023540000000821237 s)]
n = 100,000:         π ≈ 3.14048          [0:00:00.001509 (Raw time: 0.0015089999999986503 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.143396         [0:00:00.014025 (Raw time: 0.014025000000003729 s)]
n = 10,000,000:      π ≈ 3.14113          [0:00:00.123001 (Raw time: 0.12300090000002228 s)]
n = 100,000,000:     π ≈ 3.1412414        [0:00:00.804258 (Raw time: 0.8042575999999713 s)]
n = 500,000,000:     π ≈ 3.141718144      [0:00:04.104100 (Raw time: 4.104099899999994 s)]

Using non-parallel count_points_in_circle
n = 10:              π ≈ 2.8              [0:00:00.000072 (Raw time: 7.189999996626284e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 3.2              [0:00:00.000023 (Raw time: 2.3100000021258893e-05 s)]
n = 100:             π ≈ 3.24             [0:00:00.000019 (Raw time: 1.86000000326203e-05 s)]
n = 1,000:           π ≈ 3.124            [0:00:00.000037 (Raw time: 3.739999999652355e-05 s)]
n = 10,000:          π ≈ 3.1264           [0:00:00.000120 (Raw time: 0.00012040000001434237 s)]
n = 100,000:         π ≈ 3.14256          [0:00:00.001055 (Raw time: 0.0010548999999855369 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.141884         [0:00:00.010567 (Raw time: 0.010566699999969842 s)]
n = 10,000,000:      π ≈ 3.1413664        [0:00:00.107006 (Raw time: 0.10700550000001385 s)]
n = 100,000,000:     π ≈ 3.14188264       [0:00:00.865470 (Raw time: 0.8654702999999699 s)]
n = 500,000,000:     π ≈ 3.141582376      [0:00:04.014441 (Raw time: 4.01444140000001 s)]

Improved version:
n = 10:              π ≈ 2.8              [0:00:00.000067 (Raw time: 6.719999998949788e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 2.4              [0:00:00.000016 (Raw time: 1.550000001770968e-05 s)]
n = 100:             π ≈ 3.24             [0:00:00.000029 (Raw time: 2.8799999995499093e-05 s)]
n = 1,000:           π ≈ 3.192            [0:00:00.000022 (Raw time: 2.1799999956328975e-05 s)]
n = 10,000:          π ≈ 3.172            [0:00:00.000185 (Raw time: 0.00018489999996518236 s)]
n = 100,000:         π ≈ 3.14124          [0:00:00.001362 (Raw time: 0.0013624999999706233 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.143404         [0:00:00.013065 (Raw time: 0.013065499999981967 s)]
n = 10,000,000:      π ≈ 3.1418088        [0:00:00.112366 (Raw time: 0.11236619999999675 s)]
n = 100,000,000:     π ≈ 3.141952         [0:00:00.682029 (Raw time: 0.6820288000000119 s)]
n = 500,000,000:     π ≈ 3.141576848      [0:00:03.210755 (Raw time: 3.210754800000018 s)]

Comparison:
n = 10:              improved ≤ non-parallel ≤ parallel
n = 10:              improved ≤ non-parallel ≤ parallel
n = 100:             non-parallel ≤ improved ≤ parallel
n = 1,000:           improved ≤ non-parallel ≤ parallel
n = 10,000:          non-parallel ≤ improved ≤ parallel
n = 100,000:         non-parallel ≤ improved ≤ parallel
n = 1,000,000:       non-parallel ≤ improved ≤ parallel
n = 10,000,000:      non-parallel ≤ improved ≤ parallel
n = 100,000,000:     improved ≤ parallel ≤ non-parallel
n = 500,000,000:     improved ≤ non-parallel ≤ parallel

Results without pre-allocation:
Using JIT compilation without caching
Not using preallocated buffers

Using parallel count_points_in_circle
n = 10:              π ≈ 3.2              [0:00:00.003375 (Raw time: 0.0033753000000160682 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 3.2              [0:00:00.000062 (Raw time: 6.170000006022747e-05 s)]
n = 100:             π ≈ 3.2              [0:00:00.000059 (Raw time: 5.86999999541149e-05 s)]
n = 1,000:           π ≈ 3.112            [0:00:00.000099 (Raw time: 9.939999995367543e-05 s)]
n = 10,000:          π ≈ 3.1276           [0:00:00.000183 (Raw time: 0.00018330000000332802 s)]
n = 100,000:         π ≈ 3.13956          [0:00:00.001689 (Raw time: 0.0016891000000214262 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.142456         [0:00:00.015140 (Raw time: 0.015140099999939594 s)]
n = 10,000,000:      π ≈ 3.1418444        [0:00:00.128062 (Raw time: 0.1280623000000105 s)]
n = 100,000,000:     π ≈ 3.14139292       [0:00:00.831049 (Raw time: 0.8310494999999491 s)]
n = 500,000,000:     π ≈ 3.141657016      [0:00:04.522461 (Raw time: 4.522460500000079 s)]

Using non-parallel count_points_in_circle
n = 10:              π ≈ 3.2              [0:00:00.323710 (Raw time: 0.3237104999999474 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 2.8              [0:00:00.000035 (Raw time: 3.4599999935380765e-05 s)]
n = 100:             π ≈ 3.24             [0:00:00.000022 (Raw time: 2.1899999978813867e-05 s)]
n = 1,000:           π ≈ 3.14             [0:00:00.000044 (Raw time: 4.419999993388046e-05 s)]
n = 10,000:          π ≈ 3.1244           [0:00:00.000150 (Raw time: 0.00014989999999670545 s)]
n = 100,000:         π ≈ 3.13744          [0:00:00.000897 (Raw time: 0.0008967999999640597 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.143708         [0:00:00.008511 (Raw time: 0.008510500000056709 s)]
n = 10,000,000:      π ≈ 3.1406824        [0:00:00.084274 (Raw time: 0.08427370000003975 s)]
n = 100,000,000:     π ≈ 3.14154872       [0:00:00.902473 (Raw time: 0.9024734999999282 s)]
n = 500,000,000:     π ≈ 3.141605384      [0:00:04.363011 (Raw time: 4.363010799999984 s)]

Improved version:
n = 10:              π ≈ 3.2              [0:00:00.407473 (Raw time: 0.40747319999991305 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 2.8              [0:00:00.000034 (Raw time: 3.4199999959128036e-05 s)]
n = 100:             π ≈ 3.16             [0:00:00.000019 (Raw time: 1.9299999962640868e-05 s)]
n = 1,000:           π ≈ 3.184            [0:00:00.000021 (Raw time: 2.0999999946980097e-05 s)]
n = 10,000:          π ≈ 3.1388           [0:00:00.000233 (Raw time: 0.0002328000000488828 s)]
n = 100,000:         π ≈ 3.13748          [0:00:00.001424 (Raw time: 0.0014244999999846186 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.140832         [0:00:00.015200 (Raw time: 0.015200499999991735 s)]
n = 10,000,000:      π ≈ 3.1420484        [0:00:00.131624 (Raw time: 0.13162439999996423 s)]
n = 100,000,000:     π ≈ 3.14133648       [0:00:00.913009 (Raw time: 0.9130087999999432 s)]
n = 500,000,000:     π ≈ 3.141633632      [0:00:04.001366 (Raw time: 4.001365899999996 s)]

Comparison:
n = 10:              parallel ≤ non-parallel ≤ improved
n = 10:              improved ≤ non-parallel ≤ parallel
n = 100:             improved ≤ non-parallel ≤ parallel
n = 1,000:           improved ≤ non-parallel ≤ parallel
n = 10,000:          non-parallel ≤ parallel ≤ improved
n = 100,000:         non-parallel ≤ improved ≤ parallel
n = 1,000,000:       non-parallel ≤ parallel ≤ improved
n = 10,000,000:      non-parallel ≤ parallel ≤ improved
n = 100,000,000:     parallel ≤ non-parallel ≤ improved
n = 500,000,000:     improved ≤ non-parallel ≤ parallel


Your program spends most of its runtime on rng.random((n, 2)). That's why parallelization doesn't help. In general, random number generation is a very intensive process.

Is it also random in terms of the time it takes? That would explain the inconsistency of the results.

TL;DR: Benchmarking is hard and requires a lot of care. What you can observe is a combination of different complex low-level problems. The biggest issue seems to be the overhead of pages faults for big n values. Allocations introduce a significant overhead for small n values.

Under the hood
First of all, we need analyse the variability of the performance results on multiple runs (as pointed out in the previous post). This is critical to know whether we can compare results and more specifically whether the performance gap is just smaller then the noise of the environnement. It is also critical to avoid measuring unwanted effects and discover performance issues of the implementation.
Here are results on my machine with a i5-9600KF CPU:
Using JIT compilation without caching

Using parallel count_points_in_circle
n = 10:              π ≈ 3.2              [0:00:00.000072 (Raw time: 7.239996921271086e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 3.6              [0:00:00.000035 (Raw time: 3.490003291517496e-05 s)]
n = 100:             π ≈ 3.04             [0:00:00.000032 (Raw time: 3.1800009310245514e-05 s)]
n = 1,000:           π ≈ 3.096            [0:00:00.000034 (Raw time: 3.370002377778292e-05 s)]
n = 10,000:          π ≈ 3.1232           [0:00:00.000117 (Raw time: 0.00011669995728880167 s)]
n = 100,000:         π ≈ 3.14504          [0:00:00.000929 (Raw time: 0.0009286999702453613 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.142864         [0:00:00.008691 (Raw time: 0.008691399940289557 s)]
n = 10,000,000:      π ≈ 3.1420324        [0:00:00.084783 (Raw time: 0.08478260005358607 s)]
n = 100,000,000:     π ≈ 3.141647         [0:00:00.847835 (Raw time: 0.8478348000207916 s)]

Using non-parallel count_points_in_circle
n = 10:              π ≈ 2.4              [0:00:00.065648 (Raw time: 0.06564839999191463 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 2.8              [0:00:00.000029 (Raw time: 2.929999027401209e-05 s)]
n = 100:             π ≈ 3.44             [0:00:00.000016 (Raw time: 1.6300007700920105e-05 s)]
n = 1,000:           π ≈ 3.272            [0:00:00.000026 (Raw time: 2.5999965146183968e-05 s)]
n = 10,000:          π ≈ 3.1256           [0:00:00.000089 (Raw time: 8.919998072087765e-05 s)]
n = 100,000:         π ≈ 3.14488          [0:00:00.000976 (Raw time: 0.0009761999826878309 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.1422           [0:00:00.009300 (Raw time: 0.00930010003503412 s)]
n = 10,000,000:      π ≈ 3.1412352        [0:00:00.092240 (Raw time: 0.09224000002723187 s)]
n = 100,000,000:     π ≈ 3.14135808       [0:00:00.916074 (Raw time: 0.9160742999520153 s)]

Improved version:
n = 10:              π ≈ 2.8              [0:00:00.057552 (Raw time: 0.0575522999279201 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 3.6              [0:00:00.000056 (Raw time: 5.5699958465993404e-05 s)]
n = 100:             π ≈ 3.24             [0:00:00.000019 (Raw time: 1.880002673715353e-05 s)]
n = 1,000:           π ≈ 3.14             [0:00:00.000022 (Raw time: 2.1900050342082977e-05 s)]
n = 10,000:          π ≈ 3.1384           [0:00:00.000122 (Raw time: 0.0001221999991685152 s)]
n = 100,000:         π ≈ 3.1382           [0:00:00.000905 (Raw time: 0.0009048000210896134 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.142556         [0:00:00.008651 (Raw time: 0.008650899981148541 s)]
n = 10,000,000:      π ≈ 3.1414452        [0:00:00.085165 (Raw time: 0.08516450005117804 s)]
n = 100,000,000:     π ≈ 3.14160088       [0:00:00.847657 (Raw time: 0.8476569000631571 s)]

Comparison:
n = 10:              parallel ≤ improved ≤ non-parallel
n = 10:              non-parallel ≤ parallel ≤ improved
n = 100:             non-parallel ≤ improved ≤ parallel
n = 1,000:           improved ≤ non-parallel ≤ parallel
n = 10,000:          non-parallel ≤ parallel ≤ improved
n = 100,000:         improved ≤ parallel ≤ non-parallel
n = 1,000,000:       improved ≤ parallel ≤ non-parallel
n = 10,000,000:      parallel ≤ improved ≤ non-parallel
n = 100,000,000:     improved ≤ parallel ≤ non-parallel

We can see that the parallel version is generally slightly faster than the sequential one when n is big. This is expected except the scalability is bad. The problem is that the generation of random numbers is expensive and also not parallel as pointed out by @ken in comments. On my machine it takes about ~85% of the time. I expect this to be higher on your machine regarding your performance results. One solution is simply to generate number in the parallel loop. However, each thread needs to use its own random number generator to avoid race conditions. This also means that the results will be different between the sequential and parallel version. One solution to avoid that is to compute the operation chunk by chunk and attribute a seed to each chunk. Chunks can be computed in parallel.
We can also see that the first run is slower than the second one. Skipping it is a good idea. This is common in benchmarks. Note that the first benchmarked implementation is faster than others but if we change the order of the benchmarked implementations then we get different results for n=10. The order matter. Here is another run with a different order where we can see that the first implementation is still fast while it was slow before. Results are consistent between multiple runs.
Improved version:
n = 10:              π ≈ 3.2              [0:00:00.000040 (Raw time: 4.009995609521866e-05 s)]
[...]

Using parallel count_points_in_circle
n = 10:              π ≈ 3.6              [0:00:00.068012 (Raw time: 0.06801209994591773 s)]
[...]

Using non-parallel count_points_in_circle
n = 10:              π ≈ 2.8              [0:00:00.069424 (Raw time: 0.06942409998737276 s)]
[...]

While we cannot explain this effect so far (it is explained below), it is often a good idea in benchmarking to mix the order of benchmarked functions so to mitigate the effect of the execution order, or at least to check once if this impact performance results. An even better solution is to study this variability so to understand where it comes from and then remove it (or mitigate it using a better way than just changing the order randomly).
Regarding the variance of the results, here is the result for n=1_000_000 (without changing the order so to analyse the effects rather than trying to mitigate them):
Using parallel count_points_in_circle
n = 10:              π ≈ 3.2              [0:00:00.000067 (Raw time: 6.700004450976849e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 3.6              [0:00:00.000034 (Raw time: 3.390002530068159e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 3.2              [0:00:00.000029 (Raw time: 2.8699985705316067e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 2.4              [0:00:00.000028 (Raw time: 2.829998265951872e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 2.4              [0:00:00.000023 (Raw time: 2.3399945348501205e-05 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.14116          [0:00:00.008865 (Raw time: 0.008865099982358515 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.1432           [0:00:00.009421 (Raw time: 0.009420599904842675 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.14128          [0:00:00.009514 (Raw time: 0.0095135000301525 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.141468         [0:00:00.009350 (Raw time: 0.009350200067274272 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.144512         [0:00:00.009279 (Raw time: 0.009278699988499284 s)]

Using non-parallel count_points_in_circle
n = 10:              π ≈ 2.8              [0:00:00.000649 (Raw time: 0.0006492000538855791 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 3.6              [0:00:00.000016 (Raw time: 1.5900004655122757e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 3.6              [0:00:00.000017 (Raw time: 1.6900012269616127e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 3.2              [0:00:00.000014 (Raw time: 1.3999990187585354e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 2.4              [0:00:00.000013 (Raw time: 1.2999982573091984e-05 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.14134          [0:00:00.009231 (Raw time: 0.009231199976056814 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.14328          [0:00:00.010144 (Raw time: 0.010143899940885603 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.138916         [0:00:00.009952 (Raw time: 0.009952099993824959 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.139616         [0:00:00.009751 (Raw time: 0.009751199977472425 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.139168         [0:00:00.009879 (Raw time: 0.00987930002156645 s)]

Improved version:
n = 10:              π ≈ 4.0              [0:00:00.000657 (Raw time: 0.0006566999945789576 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 3.2              [0:00:00.000017 (Raw time: 1.68998958542943e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 2.8              [0:00:00.000013 (Raw time: 1.3499986380338669e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 2.4              [0:00:00.000013 (Raw time: 1.3399985618889332e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 3.6              [0:00:00.000013 (Raw time: 1.3199984095990658e-05 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.140924         [0:00:00.008729 (Raw time: 0.008728599990718067 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.141284         [0:00:00.009376 (Raw time: 0.009375799912959337 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.140992         [0:00:00.009431 (Raw time: 0.009431499987840652 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.137444         [0:00:00.009418 (Raw time: 0.009417900000698864 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.14126          [0:00:00.009260 (Raw time: 0.00925989996176213 s)]

We can clearly see that there is a significant variability of the execution time. It is close to 10%. This variability is so big that it does not makes sense to compare the different implementation. If you want to be rigorous, you can compute the standard-deviation (on much more runs) and use statistical tests so to state whether one implementation is statistically faster than another. More specifically compute the p-value of a such a tests (defining the probability for a test-case performance to be statistically different of another one).
Note that overhead of Numpy functions is typically of few microseconds and it tends to be instable (for many complex implementation-dependent reasons). Big allocations can be also takes 1-10 µs due to rather expensive system calls. The performance of such allocations is pretty unstable since it depends of the state of the OS and the hardware. This fully explains the variability of the results for n=10 (except maybe the first call), but not n=1_000_000.
To investigate the overhead of the allocation and the Numba parallel loop, we can simply remove them and analyse the timings. Note that we need to be careful since Numba can completely optimize the dead code out. Here is the timing without the main computing loop (but still with allocations):
Using parallel count_points_in_circle
n = 10:              π ≈ 2.8              [0:00:00.000083 (Raw time: 8.33999365568161e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 3.6              [0:00:00.000026 (Raw time: 2.6400084607303143e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 2.8              [0:00:00.000029 (Raw time: 2.859998494386673e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 3.6              [0:00:00.000025 (Raw time: 2.5099958293139935e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 3.2              [0:00:00.000023 (Raw time: 2.280005719512701e-05 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.140324         [0:00:00.008461 (Raw time: 0.008461099932901561 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.139792         [0:00:00.009094 (Raw time: 0.00909399997908622 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.142352         [0:00:00.009089 (Raw time: 0.009088999941013753 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.14354          [0:00:00.009371 (Raw time: 0.009370599989779294 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 3.142652         [0:00:00.009059 (Raw time: 0.009059199946932495 s)]

Using non-parallel count_points_in_circle
n = 10:              π ≈ 0.0              [0:00:00.000644 (Raw time: 0.0006444000173360109 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 0.0              [0:00:00.000018 (Raw time: 1.8000020645558834e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 0.0              [0:00:00.000014 (Raw time: 1.3599987141788006e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 0.0              [0:00:00.000015 (Raw time: 1.4899997040629387e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 0.0              [0:00:00.000013 (Raw time: 1.2899981811642647e-05 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0.0              [0:00:00.007921 (Raw time: 0.00792070000898093 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0.0              [0:00:00.008640 (Raw time: 0.008639700012281537 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0.0              [0:00:00.008546 (Raw time: 0.008545699995011091 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0.0              [0:00:00.008591 (Raw time: 0.008591299992986023 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0.0              [0:00:00.008541 (Raw time: 0.008540900074876845 s)]

Improved version:
n = 10:              π ≈ 0.0              [0:00:00.000732 (Raw time: 0.0007323999889194965 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 0.0              [0:00:00.000019 (Raw time: 1.8699909560382366e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 0.0              [0:00:00.000014 (Raw time: 1.4399993233382702e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 0.0              [0:00:00.000014 (Raw time: 1.3900105841457844e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 0.0              [0:00:00.000014 (Raw time: 1.3699987903237343e-05 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0.0              [0:00:00.007986 (Raw time: 0.007986400043591857 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0.0              [0:00:00.008555 (Raw time: 0.008555100066587329 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0.0              [0:00:00.008666 (Raw time: 0.008665500092320144 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0.0              [0:00:00.008628 (Raw time: 0.00862750003580004 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0.0              [0:00:00.008582 (Raw time: 0.008581700036302209 s)]

Here is the same without allocations nor Numba calls:
Using parallel count_points_in_circle
n = 10:              π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.000012 (Raw time: 1.1899974197149277e-05 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.000007 (Raw time: 6.6999346017837524e-06 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.000006 (Raw time: 5.999929271638393e-06 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.000006 (Raw time: 5.799927748739719e-06 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.000006 (Raw time: 5.600042641162872e-06 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.007962 (Raw time: 0.007962200092151761 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.008590 (Raw time: 0.008589700097218156 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.008600 (Raw time: 0.008599899942055345 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.008600 (Raw time: 0.008599699940532446 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.008584 (Raw time: 0.008583900053054094 s)]

Using non-parallel count_points_in_circle
n = 10:              π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.000615 (Raw time: 0.0006147000240162015 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.000009 (Raw time: 8.699949830770493e-06 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.000007 (Raw time: 6.9999368861317635e-06 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.000006 (Raw time: 5.900044925510883e-06 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.000006 (Raw time: 5.800044164061546e-06 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.007936 (Raw time: 0.00793560000602156 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.008625 (Raw time: 0.008624699898064137 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.008583 (Raw time: 0.008582800044678152 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.008590 (Raw time: 0.008589799981564283 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.008606 (Raw time: 0.008606199990026653 s)]

Improved version:
n = 10:              π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.000622 (Raw time: 0.0006216999609023333 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.000007 (Raw time: 6.8999361246824265e-06 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.000006 (Raw time: 5.800044164061546e-06 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.000006 (Raw time: 5.700043402612209e-06 s)]
n = 10:              π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.000006 (Raw time: 5.600042641162872e-06 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.007919 (Raw time: 0.007919499999843538 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.008563 (Raw time: 0.008562699891626835 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.008550 (Raw time: 0.008549700025469065 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.008663 (Raw time: 0.00866320007480681 s)]
n = 1,000,000:       π ≈ 0                [0:00:00.008837 (Raw time: 0.008836599998176098 s)]

We can see that the Numpy random number generation (RNG) takes a significant fraction of the time for both n=10 and n=1_000_000 (especially the later) and results are more stable only with only the RNG call, except the first call for both n=10 and n=1_000_000. Thus, skipping the first n=10 is not enough. Moreover, it shows the first-call overhead apparently comes from Numpy and not Numba nor allocations though they contribute to get more unstable results. Last but not least, the first run is faster for n=1_000_000 which is very unusual unless there is some frequency scaling enabled (e.g. turbo-boost), which is not the case on my machine. Let us focus on the Numpy call.
This problem is mainly due to page faults on Windows (and also the big allocation Numpy needs to do for the output array for n=10). Indeed, when an array is allocated, pages are virtually allocated but not physically mapped and they also need to be cleared (i.e. set to 0) to avoid data leaking from one application to another (e.g. browser's passwords). Page faults are very expensive and it is generally done during a first touch to save a bit of physical memory (since programs tend not to use all the memory they allocate in practice) and delay the overheads (so to avoid allocations being much more expensive). Operating systems like Windows and Linux react differently when it comes to page faults and especially page clearing. AFAIK, Windows runs a prefetching kernel thread to reset pages to zero so pages can be reused later by application as quickly as possible (while Linux do not use such a kernel thread AFAIK). When pages are recycled too quickly by an application (i.e. the application allocate a big buffer, and then release it in a short-timed loop) like in our case, the kernel thread is not fast enough then the application is slowed down. Note that the kernel thread seems not to run when the application sleep (passively or actively). Its behaviour is pretty weird to me. Anyway, page faults are expensive whatever the OS used so it is better to avoid them. One way to do that is to preallocate arrays. This also avoid doing big allocations repeatedly.
I can reproduce the problem with this program:
from datetime import timedelta
from time import perf_counter
import numpy as np

withPreallocation = False       #  <----- Set it to True to avoid expensive page faults
rng = np.random.default_rng()

if withPreallocation:
    buffer = np.full((1000_000, 2), 0.0)

def main():
    n_values = np.arange(1, 0)
    n_values = np.concatenate(
        ([10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1000_000, 1000_000, 1000_000, 1000_000, 1000_000, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1000_000, 1000_000, 1000_000, 1000_000, 1000_000], n_values)
    )
    time_results = np.empty((len(n_values), 3), dtype=np.float64)
    for i, n in enumerate(n_values):
        start = perf_counter()
        if withPreallocation:
            points = rng.random((n, 2), out=buffer[:n])
        else:
            points = rng.random((n, 2))
        end = perf_counter()
        duration = end - start
        delta = timedelta(seconds=duration)
        time_results[i, 1] = duration
        elapsed_msg = (
            f"[{delta} (Raw time: {duration} s)]"
            if delta
            else f"[Raw time: {duration} s]"
        )
        print(f"n = {n:,}:".ljust(20), elapsed_msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Here are results with and without preallocations:
Without preallocation (like in the initial code):
    n = 10:              [0:00:00.000009 (Raw time: 8.599949069321156e-06 s)]
    n = 10:              [0:00:00.000014 (Raw time: 1.4099990949034691e-05 s)]
    n = 10:              [0:00:00.000008 (Raw time: 7.999944500625134e-06 s)]
    n = 10:              [0:00:00.000006 (Raw time: 5.600042641162872e-06 s)]
    n = 10:              [0:00:00.000005 (Raw time: 5.300040356814861e-06 s)]
    n = 1,000,000:       [0:00:00.007893 (Raw time: 0.007893400033935905 s)]
    n = 1,000,000:       [0:00:00.008603 (Raw time: 0.008603000082075596 s)]
    n = 1,000,000:       [0:00:00.008540 (Raw time: 0.00853989995084703 s)]
    n = 1,000,000:       [0:00:00.008634 (Raw time: 0.008633900084532797 s)]
    n = 1,000,000:       [0:00:00.008551 (Raw time: 0.008551400038413703 s)]
    n = 10:              [0:00:00.000634 (Raw time: 0.0006342000560835004 s)]
    n = 10:              [0:00:00.000014 (Raw time: 1.4499993994832039e-05 s)]
    n = 10:              [0:00:00.000006 (Raw time: 5.899928510189056e-06 s)]
    n = 10:              [0:00:00.000005 (Raw time: 5.400041118264198e-06 s)]
    n = 10:              [0:00:00.000005 (Raw time: 5.09992241859436e-06 s)]
    n = 1,000,000:       [0:00:00.007878 (Raw time: 0.00787780003156513 s)]
    n = 1,000,000:       [0:00:00.008541 (Raw time: 0.008541099959984422 s)]
    n = 1,000,000:       [0:00:00.008531 (Raw time: 0.008530599996447563 s)]
    n = 1,000,000:       [0:00:00.008567 (Raw time: 0.008567100041545928 s)]
    n = 1,000,000:       [0:00:00.008527 (Raw time: 0.008526899968273938 s)]

With preallocation (fix):
    n = 10:              [0:00:00.000012 (Raw time: 1.179997343569994e-05 s)]
    n = 10:              [0:00:00.000007 (Raw time: 6.900052540004253e-06 s)]
    n = 10:              [0:00:00.000009 (Raw time: 9.299954399466515e-06 s)]
    n = 10:              [0:00:00.000011 (Raw time: 1.0599964298307896e-05 s)]
    n = 10:              [0:00:00.000006 (Raw time: 6.200047209858894e-06 s)]
    n = 1,000,000:       [0:00:00.006332 (Raw time: 0.006332300021313131 s)]
    n = 1,000,000:       [0:00:00.006330 (Raw time: 0.006329700001515448 s)]
    n = 1,000,000:       [0:00:00.006322 (Raw time: 0.0063218999421224 s)]
    n = 1,000,000:       [0:00:00.006321 (Raw time: 0.006320800050161779 s)]
    n = 1,000,000:       [0:00:00.006328 (Raw time: 0.006328399991616607 s)]
    n = 10:              [0:00:00.000009 (Raw time: 9.400071576237679e-06 s)]
    n = 10:              [0:00:00.000006 (Raw time: 6.100046448409557e-06 s)]
    n = 10:              [0:00:00.000006 (Raw time: 6.300047971308231e-06 s)]
    n = 10:              [0:00:00.000006 (Raw time: 6.00004568696022e-06 s)]
    n = 10:              [0:00:00.000006 (Raw time: 6.100046448409557e-06 s)]
    n = 1,000,000:       [0:00:00.006326 (Raw time: 0.006325999973341823 s)]
    n = 1,000,000:       [0:00:00.006327 (Raw time: 0.006326999980956316 s)]
    n = 1,000,000:       [0:00:00.006326 (Raw time: 0.006325799971818924 s)]
    n = 1,000,000:       [0:00:00.006336 (Raw time: 0.0063356999307870865 s)]
    n = 1,000,000:       [0:00:00.006322 (Raw time: 0.006321700057014823 s)]

This solves the variability issues and also make the execution significantly faster! Note that there is the same issue in the Numba code with in_circle. You should preallocate/reuse this array if possible to avoid paying the overhead of page faults, though this array contains boolean of 1 byte so this is less critical. Page faults can also decrease the scalability of applications on Windows (still due to the kernel thread) while I did not observed this issue on Linux so far (though page faults are still expensive).
Note that the big overhead with n=10 happening sometimes is also gone! I think this is because the internal allocation caused a system call waiting for the kernel thread to end its work. Indeed, this overhead of 634 µs is relatively close to the performance gap between the first execution and the other ones: 8541 - 7877 = 664 µs.

Thanks for your informative and insightful answer. Please look at the edit I made. I modified the code to pre-allocate the array as you suggested, but the parallel version still seems to underperform.

Your code still do many pages faults because np.empty does not map the pages in physical memory. The buffers needs to be filled to force pages to be mapped and prevent page fault to happen. This is why I used np.full in my code. Once fixed, results are more stable and the non-parallel version is always slower than others for big n values on my current machine (on Windows).

Regarding the performance of the parallel version, pages faults and allocations are meant to reduce variability of the results, not to make the parallel version scale. For scalability I explicitly stated this in the answer: "The problem is that the generation of random numbers is expensive and also not parallel as pointed out by @ken in comments. On my machine it takes about ~85% of the time. I expect this to be higher on your machine regarding your performance results. One solution is simply to generate number in the parallel loop."

Can you point to an example on how to generate random numbers in parallel with numba? numba hides the parallelization from the user, so I can't pass a generator or a seed to the worker threads, and I couldn't find how to do this. I tried changing all the np.empty commands to np.full as suggested, but it doesn't help reducing variability of the results. Sometimes I get that the parallel version is faster for large n and sometimes it's slower.

Well just write a loop with nb.prange (compiled with parallel=True) calling np.random.rand(). The seed will be different for each thread in Numba. Please see this post. It also provide an optimized RNG. Note that each thread need to work on a different RNG (which is the case by default for global Numpy functions). If you care about reproducibility between sequential and parallel code, then see Random seeds and multithreading in numba.

Regarding np.full, it was enough on the machine I used to do the test to get significantly more stable results. There was some issue due to the background activity and the governor but this is something you should set up for all benchmark (e.g. frequency scaling, turbo, etc. as stated in my answer). It is frequent for notebooks to have instable timings in benchmark due to such things.

Note that for large N Windows can compress memory and if you run out of memory it can swap it. This can have a strong impact on performance and stability. I assumed so far there was clearly enough memory and compression was not done too.

From my understanding, it’s recommended to use numpy Generator instead of global functions such as np.random.rand, so I prefer this. According to the documentation of numba, however, it looks like I shouldn’t call any Generator function with parallel=True.

You can use generator if you want but they need not to be shared by multiple threads (simultaneously). This is the only contraint. If you do that (without protection/synchronization), then there will be an undefined behaviour (e.g. data corruption, crash, random behaviour, etc.) due to a race condition.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
